How to add binary dependencies (e.g., Ghostscript) in Digital Ocean Functions for PHP?
I'm building a PHP function on Digital Ocean Functions that requires Ghostscript as a dependency. Previously, I used AWS Lambda with Node.js and added dependencies using layers, but I’m not sure if Digital Ocean Functions offers a similar option.
The DO documentation on Functions mentions using lib/build.sh for installing runtime-specific dependencies (e.g., composer install for PHP), but I can't find details on adding system-level binaries. Has anyone successfully added binary dependencies to a Digital Ocean Function environment, and if so, could you share your approach?
